# AWS Lambda Versioning of Same S3 .jar Object Source

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

One of the code sources for an AWS Lambda can be [a `.jar` object in an S3 bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-package.html).

If the contents of the jar is updated in S3, while retaining the same object key, and a new [Lambda function version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-versions.html) is created then do both versions behave the same according to the current jar?  Or does each Lambda version retain a separate copy of the jar file and therefore behave differently?

Put another way: does the source .jar have to be a unique object in the S3 bucket in order for Lambda versioning to work as expected?

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: Are you asking if lambda will prevent you from deploying a new version if the jar is unchanged?

Comment: @Paolo No, I am asking if the 2 different versions that exist will behave identically or differently based on their respective .jar files.